# Microeconomics book for a mathematician?

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request

Background

I have studied matematics for 4 years at the university, both pure and applied, e.g. topology, functional analysis and valuation of Derivative Assets. Currently I'm taking a course called advanced microeconomics, using Hal Varian Microeconomics Analysis. I feel that this book has a lot of explaining text that I would better understand with "pure math definition". E.g. Just defining risk-averse as a concave utility function.

So I wonder if there is book more related to the format of a math textbook that I can use as a secondary book, to get another perspective? I'm asking this question because during my studies I often find myself reading through a lot of text and when I arrive at a mathematical definition in the book or e.g. wikipedia, then I can understand what the author is trying to tell me.

I have looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945210/good-economics-textbooks) and [this](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4875/mathematical-micro-macro-economics-textbook-recommendation) questions but both are >2 years old, thus maybe there is something new on the market?

Comment: I'm not sure asking for a more recent book is sufficient to have a new question. Have you seen the books recommended in those questions? Are you unsatisfied with them?

Comment: @luchonacho I looked at "Mas-Colell, Whinston, and Green's Microeconomic" but it seemed similar to Varian. Also comment suggested that MWG and also others recommended were not very mathematical.

Comment: I don't understand your question then. MWG pretty much employs the "definition-theorem/proposition-proof" style commonly seen in math texts. I don't know how much more "mathy" one can get in terms of the presentation style than MWG.

Comment: @HerrK. Okey! This is my first economics course, and it feels like there is a lot of powerful mathematics behind it, hence the question. Thanks for you input.

Comment: The kind of "powerful mathematics" in economics dwarfs in comparison to the kind in mathematics. But that's because of the nature of the subject. That being said, there are some high-power maths in economics as you get deeper into the field---though unlikely in your first course in econ.

Comment: I don't really get the purpose of this discussion. In comparison of Chemistry and Physics, economics as a science comes from political philosophy. It is a social science, thus the discussion is more important than proving a mathematical model. Keynes, Smith, Marx, Friedman do not use a single formula to the majority of their texts.